# How to get only the data in square brackets in PostreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to split the information that a column in PostgreSQL contains, take only information in square brackets and put it in new columns.

Exemplary value looks similar to this one:

> 'value a:(abcabva[23]), value b: bcdbcd[54]), value c:
> cdecde((53))...'

I need to get only 23 and 54 in separate columns.

Is this possible?

Thank you for the help!

Comment: Do you need to select and insert in same query? You can always `select column where values like '%[%]%' ` and then extract and insert in next step.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want these in separate *rows*:

```
select replace(el[1], '[', '')
from (values ('value a:(abcabva[23]), value b: bcdbcd[54]), value c: cdecde((53))...')
     ) v(str) cross join lateral
     regexp_matches(v.str, '\[[^\]]+', 'g') el;
```

If you do want them in separate columns, then:

```
select regexp_replace(str, '^[^\[]*\[([^\]]+)\].*$', '\1') as col1,
       regexp_replace(str, '^[^\[]*\[[^\]]+\].*\[([^\]]+)\].*$', '\1') as col2
from (values ('value a:(abcabva[23]), value b: bcdbcd[54]), value c: cdecde((53))...')
     ) v(str) ;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=b7cacf85dafda5c23c9290e2b5574c72) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `regexp_matches()`, as in:

```
SELECT regexp_matches(
  'value a:(abcabva[23]), value b: bcdbcd[54]), value c: cdecde((53))',
  '\[([0-9]+)\]', 
  'g');
```

Result:

```
regexp_matches
--------------
["23"]
["54"]
```

See running example at [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rvJ7nwWCWdgVY5oGGZgHSg/0).